# Let G be a group, H be a subgroup of G with order m, and g ∈ G. Show that $|\{hgh^{−1}\mid h \in H\}|$ is a divisor of m.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with order $m$, and $g \in G$. Show that $|\{hgh^{−1}\mid h \in H\}|$ is a divisor of $m$.

What I know so far is that $|H| = b$ and that |{$hgh^{−1}\mid h \in H$}| is the order of the set of conjugacy classes. How would I go about solving this? My initial thoughts are expanding $(hgh^{−1})^{b}$, so $(hgh^{−1})(hgh^{−1})(hgh^{−1})...(hgh^{−1})$ = $hg(hgh^{−1})g(hgh^{−1})g..(hgh^{−1})gh^{-1}$ = $hg^{b}h^{-1}$

If $g^{m} = e$ then $(hgh^{−1})$ $\implies$ = $hg^{m}h^{−1}$ = $heh^{−1} = e$.. then following the logic, this should lead to the conclusion? Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't work. Showing that $(hgh^{-1})^m = e$ doesn't tell you enough about the size of the set of all $hgh^{-1}.$

Use the orbit-stabilizer theorem on the action of $H$ by conjugation on $G$. The set $\{hgh^{-1} : \, h \in H\}$ is an orbit, so by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, $$|\{hgh^{-1}: \, h \in H\}| = \frac{|H|}{|\{h \in H: \, hgh^{-1} = g\}|},$$ which divides $|H|.$